# How to perform item assignment in a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Let a tensor be `a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` and another tensor be `b = [1,3,0,5]`, here I want a tensorflow operation to put 1 in the tensor `a` taking the position values from the tensor `b`. Hence the output tensor will be, `[1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]`.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this ?

```
a = tf.Variable([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
b = tf.Variable([1,3,0,5])

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    update = tf.scatter_update(a,
                               b,
                               tf.tile(tf.constant([1],
                                       tf.int32),
                               b.shape))

    print(update.eval(session=sess))
```

The output is

> [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0]

Comment: I have used tf.scatter_update but during training, it is returning error, gradient registry has no entry for: ScatterUpdate, what is the problem here? How to solve it? @MohanRadhakrishnan

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question with clear details so that others can try to answer too.